# Как слинковать библиотеку с помощью CMake (library not found)?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, link

У меня стоит MacOS 10.15 Catalina. Пытаюсь слинковать исполняемый файл с библиотекой, которая лежит в другом каталоге. Однако при линковке возникает такая ошибка:

```
Scanning dependencies of target example1
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example1.dir/lab03/examples/example1.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable example1
ld: library not found for -lprint
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [example1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/example1.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Вот мой **CMakeLists.txt**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь, все перерыл, но нет ответа. Спасибо

Comment: Попыток указать линкеру, где искать эту библиотеку, не видно.

Comment: все работает если собирать вручную

Comment: но да полный путь показывал, не работает https://github.com/Evgengrmit/lab03 вот здесь все мои исходники

Comment: но если все в одном CMakeLists и библиотеку и  исполняемые собирать то все ок а вот если ликовать из другого каталога то все вылетает

Comment: @ЕвгенийГригорьев текстовую информация следует приводить текстом, а не скрином

Comment: @ЕвгенийГригорьев крайне не рекомендуется указывать имя библиотеки в `target_link_libraries`. Вместо этого воспользуйтесь `find_library`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Большинство библиотек для `C++` имеют интеграцию с `CMake`, и их можно подключить просто через `find_package()`.

В таком случае вместо `include_directories()` используйте `find_package()` с `target_link_libraries()`:

```
find_package(<Library> REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PACKAGE_NAME} PRIVATE <Library>)
```

У `find_package()` есть 3 режима:

- **Module mode**, который ищет `Find<PackageName>.cmake` файлы по путям, которые хранятся в `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. По умолчанию он ищет в дефолтном каталоге, где установлен сам CMake, например:
  `/opt/Qt/Tools/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/`.
- **Config mode**, который ищет `<PackageName>Config.cmake` файлы по путям, которые хранятся в `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. В этом случае тоже есть дефолтные пути, которые зависят от платформы. Так же от платформы зависят правила, по которым конфиг-файл должен располагаться в иерархии каталогов библиотеки:

  ```
  <prefix>/                                                          W
  <prefix>/(cmake|CMake)/                                            W
  <prefix>/<name>*/                                                  W
  <prefix>/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/                                    W
  <prefix>/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/<name>*/                            W
  <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*/                    U
  <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/                          U
  <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/            U
  <prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*/            W/U
  <prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/                  W/U
  <prefix>/<name>*/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/    W/U
  <prefix>/<name>.framework/Resources/                               A
  <prefix>/<name>.framework/Resources/CMake/                         A
  <prefix>/<name>.framework/Versions/*/Resources/                    A
  <prefix>/<name>.framework/Versions/*/Resources/CMake/              A
  <prefix>/<name>.app/Contents/Resources/                            A
  <prefix>/<name>.app/Contents/Resources/CMake/                      A
  ```

  `W` - Windows; `U` - UNIX (Linux); `A` - macOS, iOS 
  `<prefix>` - это как раз один из путей, который лежит в `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`
- **FetchContent redirection mode**, который качает git-репу в *configure time*. А также его аналог - **ExternalProject**, который делает это в *build time*.

Если нет, бывает библиотеки поддерживают `pkg-config` (в этом случает у них должны быть `pc`-файлы), для которого у `CMake` уже есть модуль `FindPkgConfig.cmake`.

Если нет и интеграции с `pkg-config`, вот тут уже придётся вручную подключать все необходимые части сбилженой либы через: `find_library()`, `target_include_directories()`, `target_link_libraries()`, `...`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Проблема решена!

Comment: @ЕвгенийГригорьев, можешь ещё попробовать сделать через find_library(lib-print NAMES print PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lab03/include), а затем target_link_libraries(example1 lib-print)

Comment: Да я все способы объединил)